# Second UICollectionCell prototype is not displayed, what's wrong doing with the storyboard?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode-storyboard

I am learning the examples of **UICollectionView** from the book:

> 'iOS7, Push the limit', chapter 5, 'Get a Handle on Collection Views'.

By following the book, I created a second UICollectionCell prototype.

But even I configured properties the same as the example project, I didn't got the layout supposed to be (from the book, the collectionview has 3 columns, but I got 4, I did manual checked every parameters in the right palette of Xcode).

Why the storyboards have different layout in design?

And I don't get the size expected? Is there anyone kind enough to give some hints?

The first two images below are from the example project, the next two are from my project.

[image: The storyboard configure from the book example]
[image: The output of example project]

[image: The storyboard I created]
[image: The output of my project, no clue on the difference with the example]

Comment: show us the code inside UICollectionView's `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch05-CollectionViews/CollectionViewDemo/CollectionViewDemo/MKViewController.m#L90

Comment: have you linked your `IBOutlets` in in both the landscape and portrait cells in the storyboard?

Comment: Many thanks! You are right! The UI components in the portrait cell prototype hasn't got its Reference Outlets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return each cell with its identifier for each row. Like if you want different cell for particular row at index path then return that cell for that row in **cellForRowAtIdnexPath**.
for collection view you need to set each cell's layout attributes in collection view's layout delegate method to fit in the collection view's frame. Like collection view's delegate method of **sizeForItemAtIdnexPath** to set the size of each cell.
And set these properties of collection view to set your cell's in collection view's frame i.e. **minimumLineSpacing** and **minimumInteritemSpacing**.

Comment: The source code provided (https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch05-CollectionViews/CollectionViewDemo/CollectionViewDemo/MKViewController.m)  has no impl. of the delegate method 'sizeForItemAtIndexPath:....', and I did set 'Collection View - Cell Size, Min Spacing' in the 'Size Inspector'. What else can be done to change the spacing?

Comment: By looking at screens shots of story board i think you have changed your minimum spacing of cell and lines. Check for that

Comment: I am quite exhausted, the minimum spacing of cell and lines are both set to 10 as the example. I also tried to implement the flow layout delegate methods, but still in vain. I guess sth. incorrect with the vc setup or collectionview properties.